# SQl Count rows with 2 conditions on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following two tables:

comments

| comment_post_ID | comment_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | course_status |
| 2 | course_status |

postmeta

| meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- |
| lesson_course | 1 |
| lesson_course | 1 |
| lesson_course | 2 |

The Result should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [comment_post_ID] => 1
            [lessoncount] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [comment_post_ID] => 1
            [lessoncount] => 2
        )
```

And that's where I'm so far

```
SELECT
c.comment_post_ID,
C.lessoncount

FROM comments c

INNER JOIN (SELECT meta_value, count(meta_value) as lessoncount
FROM  postmeta WHERE meta_key='lesson_course') C 

WHERE c.comment_type = 'course_status'
```

The problem is I'm still getting the same lessoncount on every result. I tried so many things but I don't get... Every help much appreciated!

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY meta_value` in the subquery. And you're missing `ON c.comment_post_id = C.meta_value` in the `jOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not grouping the counts, so you're getting the total count of all the `lesson_course` rows in `postmeta`.

And you have no joining condition between the two tables, so you get a full cross product.

You don't need the subquery, you can do it with an ordinary join and grouping in the main query.

```
SELECT c.comment_post_id, COUNT(*) AS lessoncount
FROM comments AS c
JOIN postmeta AS m ON c.comment_post_id = m.meta_value
WHERE c.comment_type = 'course_status'
AND m.meta_key = 'lesson_course'
GROUP BY c.comment_post_id
```